# Get querystring in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following URL `http://localhost:81/#/payment/confirmed/success=0&invoiceid=42828852E9FFE2923CB6?useraction=canceled` and I want to get the value of the querystrings after `?` how can I do this.

What I've already tried

```
$stateProvider
.state('payment.confirmed', {
    url: '/confirmed',
    templateUrl: 'app/payment/confirmed/confirmed.html',
    controller: 'confirmedController'
})
.state('payment.confirmedWithParams', {
    url: '/confirmed/success={confirmed}&invoiceid={invoiceNumber}',
    resolve: {
        saveData: function($stateParams){
            function getUrlParameter(param) {
                    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
                        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split(/[&||?]/),
                        res;

                    console.info('sPageURL : ', sPageURL,
                                '\nwindow.location : ', window.location,
                                '\nsURLVariables : ', sURLVariables)

                    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i += 1) {
                        var paramName = sURLVariables[i],
                            sParameterName = (paramName || '').split('=');

                        if (sParameterName[0] === param) {
                            res = sParameterName[1];
                        }
                    }

                    return res;
            }

            var payment = {
                confirmed: ($stateParams.confirmed === '1'),
                invoiceNumber: $stateParams.invoiceNumber,
                userAction: getUrlParameter('useraction')
            };

            console.info('payment : ', payment)

            localStorage.setItem('payment', JSON.stringify(payment));
            window.location.href = '#/payment/confirmed';
        }
    }
});
```

This works fine except for `payment.userAction` which returns `undefined`. As far as I can see from the console logs the problem occour because the variable `sPageURL` is empty (not undefined).

Am I overcomplicating something simple or did I miss something

Comment: cant you reverse engineer it from the `$stateParams`

Comment: @entre: The `userAction` isn't part of the `$stateParams` ;-) it's from a different source, hence the `?` in front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you using too complicated coding?

You can get easy with using `$stateParams`

Just try this below code

`$stateParams.useraction`

if you want split URL concepts

```
var sPageURL = window.location.href,
sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('useraction')[1].split('=')[1]
.......
```

### Demo

[image]

Answer (score 0):

get it from $location service

```
    // given URL http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
    var searchObject = $location.search();
    // => {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}
```

Answer (score 0):

use $stateparams

```
.controller('Crtl',[ '$scope','$stateParams'
    function($scope , $stateParams ) {    
        // 
        console.log($stateParams.instanceID)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you mixed URL parameters and query parameters. 
URL parameters are just dynamic part of the URL, like in `/something/{id}/otherthing` where `id` is a variable part of the URL.
Query parameters are introduced with `?` like in `/something?foo&bar` where `foo` and `bar` are 2 query parameters.

All of them, if specified in the URL are accessible with `$stateParams`.

Depending of what you want, you can change

```
url: '/confirmed/success={confirmed}&invoiceid={invoiceNumber}?useraction=canceled',
```

into something like:

```
url: '/confirmed?confirmed&invoiceNumber&useraction',
```

Then `confirmed` and `invoiceNumber` are available in `$stateParams.confirmed` and `$stateParams.invoiceNumber`. No need to manually parse the query string. 
Same thing for `useraction`.

See [the documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) for details, because you can also have state parameters that are not visible in the URL, or define default values for query parameters.

Comment: I have no problem getting `confirmed` and `invoiceNumber` it's `useraction` I don't seem to be able to get

Comment: Well, I updated the answer. You need to specify `useraction` in the url